# C# XAML pass instance of Grid to other class

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have simple `Grid` with `Image` named TestImage and I need pass that Grid instance to other class. The other class will find TestImage and it will change `Source`.

When I try to access to `Grid` from codebehind of XAML it is OK, but when I try to pass instance of `Grid` to other class, I can not access to TestImage there.

**TestPage.xaml.cs**

```
var otherClass = new OtherClass();
otherClass.DoSomeStuff(this.GridName);
```

**OtherClass.cs**

```
public void DomeSomeStuff(Grid gridInstance)
{
    gridInstance.TestImage.Source = ....;
}
```

And I will get error message:

> 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid' does not contain a definition for
>   'TestImage' and no extension method 'TestImage' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid' could be found

I understand this error, but I do not known, how to fix it.

Can you help me please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void DomeSomeStuff(Grid gridInstance)
{
    var image = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(gridInstance, 0) as Image;
    // or var image = gridInstance.Children[0] as Image;
    // or var image = gridInstance.FindName("TestImage") as Image;
    if (image != null)
        image.Source = ...;
}
```

Comment: And is there way how to find children by Name (x:Name) not by children index?